# email reminder required

Tags: apex, community, force.com

Hi i want to set one reminder email to be sent to all 10 user’s “Profile -> SALES TEAM” members scheduled for 10 pm UK time on of every week reminding them to update their owned opportunities and accounts in SF.

Please share the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use apex scheduler to send out an email weekly to User.

Follow below steps to schedule below apex class

- From Setup, click Develop | Apex Classes and click Schedule Apex.
- Specify the name of a class that you want to schedule.
- Specify how       often the Apex class is to run.
- For Weekly—specify    one or more days      of the week the job is to
  run (such as Monday    and Wednesday)
- Specify the start and end dates     for the Apex scheduled class.
- Specify a    preferred start time
- The exact time the       job starts depends on    service
  availability.
- Click Save.

  ```
  global class SendEmailToUserClass Implements Schedulable
          {
                     global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
                      {
                                  sendmail();
                      }
                      public void sendmail()
                      {
                                  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                                  List<User> userList = [select id,email,profile.name from user where profile.name= 'SALES TEAM' ];
                                  string [] toAddress= new string[]{};
                                   for(User u:userList){
                                    toAddress.add(u.email);
                                   }                                   

                                    email.setSubject('Update Opptys and Accounts');
                                    email.setPlainTextBody('Update their your opportunities and accounts in SF');
                                     email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
                                  Messaging.sendEmail(New Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
                      }
          }
  ```

Comment: Hi, i had used your code, and in my SF Scheduled Job is running properly but i am not getting any e-mail notification. Please help me on the same.

Comment: You will not get any email... users with profile sales team will get an email

Comment: for testing purpose i had created one new user (abc123.test@gmail.com) and set the user under the same SALES TEAM profile, not getting any email. i had not changed any content from your code

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the Test class for the above code ?